# User can self-register unless email is on a blacklist

Tags: users

I want users to be able to register unless their email address is on a blacklist (including wildcards), in which case an administrator has to approve the registration. How do I go about this?

Comment: Could you provide some more details about how that "blacklist" is implemented/available in your Drupal site? Something hardcoded somewhere (eg within drupal admin)? And also if that list only would have a few entries (including wildcards), or "many" entries?

Answer (score 1):

No need to add any custom code as your requirement is just to allow visitors to register by themselves but you want to block them for log in till the administer won't approve them, if this the scenario then just go to the following URL:

**/admin/config/people/accounts**

or you can navigate through Admin Menu:

**configuration >> People >> Account Settings**

Here you can find section "Registration and Cancellation" under which you can find:

**Who can register accounts?**
Select:
**Visitors, but administrator approval is required**

Note: You can also set "***Require e-mail verification when a visitor creates an account***", if you required e-mail verification too.

For validation whether the email is in your blocked List or not you can validate it by writing your own custom validation function using:

function hook_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){

if($form_id == 'user_register_form'){

```
  $form['#validate'][] = 'your_validate_func_handler';
```

}

}

function your_validate_func_handler(&$form, &$form_state){

```
// here is your code to compare
```

}

Note: "hook" will be replaced from your custom module name.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: This is a nice response, and I thank you for it, but I'm not sure that it actually gives an answer to the question given.  I think writing a custom validation function would just prevent the user registering until they enter an email address that validates, wouldn't it? That's not what I'm trying to do.  I want users to be able to register without administrator approval normally, but if their name is on a blacklist, then the registration needs administrator approval.

Comment: Okay thanks for explaining the scenario, I am adding a new solution right in next answer please check whether that helps you or not.

Answer (score 0):

Put the account settings for 'Who can register accounts' on 'Visitors', and write a custom module that uses [hook_user_presave()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.api.php/function/hook_user_presave/7) to block accounts that match your criteria before they are saved.  Or maybe [hook_user_insert()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.api.php/function/hook_user_insert/7), then it won't catch profiles that you are manually unblocking.

Comment: I don't want to block users on the blacklist, I just want the admin to have to approve those people. So if the user email address isn't on the blacklist, they get instant access, if it is then they see the usual message that your registration has been sent to the admin for approval.

Comment: Oh ok, then just set the default to 'admin must approve' and use the hook to automatically activate accounts that don't match your criteria.

Answer (score 0):

As per your scenario just go to the following URL:

**/admin/config/people/accounts**

or you can navigate through Admin Menu:

**configuration >> People >> Account Settings**

Here you can find section "Registration and Cancellation" under which you can find:

**Who can register accounts?** Select: **Visitors**.

Write a custom module that uses [hook_user_presave()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.api.php/function/hook_user_presave/7) to change the status of accounts that matches your criteria before they are saved.

Let me try to explain:

If a visitor comes with certain email id "xyz@abc.com" so when it's registering in your site it's status would be "1" that is active, but in your hook i.e. "hook_user_presave()" you can check whether the email is in your block list or not, if yes, change its account status to "0" i.e. "blocked" in terms of Drupal and can shoot a mail to admin to notify that, one visitor wants to register in our site having mail Id exists in our block list. Ask Admin to approve him or not. 
**If notifying Admin is required**  else the visitor registered as blocked User and only Admin can approve him.

Note: Once Admin approved his account, you can using the same hook i.e. "hook_user_presave()" can update the user account status and also the block list of emails, as I think, you should update the block list as once your admin approved a blocked id so that block id won't be a part of that block list anymore.

You can check, whether the account is new or update:

if ($account->is_new){

```
  //Do things
```

}else

{

```
  //Do things
```

}

I am not good in explanation but tried. :)